# Gain at Break frequency of OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I find this formula for an op-amp written in a book:

Unity Gain Bandwidth=A*Fo

Where, A is the open loop gain of the opamp

Fo is the break frequency

What I inter from this expression is that the open loop gain of an apamp is generally defined at break frequency. But I could not find it written explicitly. I did not want to make any conclusion without being sure. Can someone tell if what I infer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

What you infer is correct. At DC the open loop gain is in the realm of 100,000 to 1,000,000 for most op-amps and this would naturally mean that the break (3 dB point) is a few hertz in frequency. Here's an example: -

[image]

It brings in the term gain-bandwidth-product i.e. the product of open-loop gain and bandwidth. For a regular op-amp having a 20 dB per decade slope (single order), the product is virtually a constant.

Picture taken from [this slide show](https://slideplayer.com/slide/10203617/).